# How to pass workbook parameters in the url to an Azure Monitor Workbook?

Tags: azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I would like to open an Azure Monitor workbook using parameters passed in the url. For example, to open the workbook named `WorkBook1` and passing in `Parameter1` with `Value1` and `Parameter2` with `Value2`, I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
https://portal.azure.com/.../workbook/WorkbookTemplateName/WorkBook1?Parameter1=Value1&Parameter2=Value2
```

This feature doesn't appear to be documented anywhere but it seems like it should exist. Is it possible to pass a workbook parameter in the url to an Azure Monitor Notebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't documented because it *really* depends on the Azure Portal's implementation of URLs, which is complicated, to put it simply.  (i don't want to hide behind the org chart here, but the history of how deep links work in the azure portal is a long and complicated story, as with any huge software project )

That being said, it is complicated and i'll look at getting better documentation about this shipped publicly (probably fastest in our [GitHub Docs](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks#readme), which eventually gets to our Azure Docs), and i'll make it as simple as possible here...

The easiest way to *start* is to open the thing you want, and then use the "Share" item in the toolbar to open the tool that can generate a starting link ("the share blade").  That generated link should have everything you need *except* the `NotebookParams` parameter below.

It shoud look something like below:

`https://portal.azure.com/#blade/[name of extension]/[Name of view]/[inputName]/[inputValue]`

The name of extension is always `AppInsightsExtension`, and the view is either `UsageNotebookBlade` if you want the item to be editable, or `WorkbookViewerBlade` if you want the item to not be editable.  (These are historical names things as they were named when they were created, so it is what it is.  we're working on cleaning a lot of this up going forward)

The `/inputname/input value` part repeats for each input to the view, and where input value is percent encoded.  The parameters you'll *probably* see set, though there may be more:

- `ComponentId/[a url encoded resource/other id]` (component id is like the "folder" where the workbook is, it could be inside "Azure Monitor" or it could be inside a specific virtual machine and this value could be a full azure resource id, etc)
- `ConfigurationId/[a url encoded workbook resource id, or community template id]`

  the configuration id may also be a template id, like "Community-[id]" instead of a resource id to a specific workbook. If a saved workbook, you'll see a full azure resource id like  `/subscriptions/blah/resourcegroups/blah/providers/microsoft.insights/workbooks/id`, which will need to be encoded as well, so you'd end up with something like `%2Fsubscriptions%2Fblah%2Fresourcegroups%2Fblah%2Fresourceprovider.resource%2Ftype%2Fid`
- The input you are specifically asking about to set some specific params to the workbook is called `NotebookParams`

  `NotebookParams/[encoded params]`   Where encoded params in a url is a percent encoded string of the JSON serialized dictionary of key/value params. (For time range params it’s a object with `durationMs` field and possibly more if custom time range was set, you can look in a workbook advanced mode JSON after setting the param to see the exact thing you need).  In this example, I have a time range param named “timeRange” set to 5 minutes, and a text param called “paramB” set to “banana”

  {​​​​​​"timeRange": {​​​​​​ "durationMs": 300000 }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​, "paramB": "banana" }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

  which get percent encoded (including spaces=%20 instead of spaces = +) to:

  `%7B%22timeRange%22%3A%20%7B%20%22durationMs%22%3A%20300000%20%7D%2C%20%22paramB%22%3A%20%22banana%22%20%7D%0D%0A`

The names of parameters must match exactly with those in the content for them to be hooked up, and they also need to be at the "top level" of the workbook.  (this won't generally work with parameters nested inside other groups)

The full url would then look something like:

`https://portal.azure.com/#blade/AppInsightsExtension/UsageNotebookBlade/ComponentId/%2Fsubscriptions%2Fblah%2Fresourcegroups%2Fblah%2Fresourceprovider.resource%2Ftype%2Fnameofresource/ConfigurationId/%2Fsubscriptions%2Fblah%2Fresourcegroups%2Fblah%2Fproviders%2Fmicrosoft.insights%2Fworkbooks%0000000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/NotebookParams/%7B%22timeRange%22%3A%20%7B%20%22durationMs%22%3A%20300000%20%7D%2C%20%22paramB%22%3A%20%22banana%22%20%7D%0D%0A`

**But: Please, please, *please*** do *not* do this to set up an "autorefresh" script in a browser to repeatedly reload the workbook from scratch.  Use the Autorefresh feature in the toolbar instead.  Autorefresh inside workbooks re-runs the queries on a schedule, which is a LOT lighter weight than loading the whole portal, all of its dependencies, our extension, all of our dependencies, etc.

If autorefresh doesn't work for you, fill out feedback inside workbooks in the Azure Portal or send me mail first initial j, lastname gardner @ microsoft with your details for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and useful response! Using your explanation, I got it working with a simple text parameter. I'd vote for the response as an answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: odd, you can't accept an answer of your own question without rep?  that's strange and probably why there are so many questions with an answer but not accepted?

Comment: So much insightful, I just had the same requirement. I was able to do that.

Comment: However, is it possible to do the same in the Log Analytics UI? Can I pass the KQL query as URL parameter for Log Analytics?

Comment: not exactly the same way because its a different view, but yes, there's a `query` field you can pass to log analytics a similar way, if it is short enough.  If it is a long query it needs to be gzip'd and base64 encoded and passed as a `q` parameter instead?

Comment: Thanks for this. Where's the best place to leave enhancement requests for Azure Workbook?

Comment: @Paolo for workbooks the best way is to do it in feedback directly in the workbook view (the toolbar for all the workbooks views should have a smiley face icon)

Answer (score 2):

As a parallel answer:  The accepted answer is technically correct, and literally answers the asked question, but the unasked question is "from where?".

- If you are outside of the azure portal and are linking *into* a workbook/template in the azure portal, the above is what you want.
- However, if you are already inside workbook content in the portal, and you want to open another workbook (or other portal views) there's a better way than the accepted answer, and that's to use links, either in the visualization settings for the visualization you are using, or by using a Links step.

  The link configuration has an option for the kind of link, "Workbook/Template view".  If using that link action in the portal, there's an entire ux for setting up where all the various inputs to the view come from, AND let you explicitly pass parameters as well, including mapping them from columns or parameters or static values.